# Ошибка скомпилированного приложения под Windows

Tags: c++, c, g++

Компилирую проект [pngwolf-zopfli](https://github.com/jibsen/pngwolf-zopfli). Параметры компиляции:

```
@echo off

set path=E:\MingW\Mingw64\32-win-dw\bin
set exe=gcc.exe
set out=_test32

set  src=pngwolf.cxx
set  rc1=galib\ga\GA1DArrayGenome.C galib\ga\GAAllele.C galib\ga\GABaseGA.C galib\ga\gabincvt.C
set  rc2=galib\ga\GAGenome.C galib\ga\GAIncGA.C galib\ga\GAParameter.C galib\ga\GAPopulation.C
set  rc3=galib\ga\garandom.C galib\ga\gaerror.C galib\ga\GAScaling.C galib\ga\GASelector.C galib\ga\GAStatistics.C
set  rc4=zlib\adler32.c zlib\compress.c zlib\crc32.c zlib\deflate.c zlib\gzclose.c zlib\gzlib.c zlib\gzread.c
set  rc5=zlib\gzwrite.c zlib\infback.c zlib\inffast.c zlib\inflate.c zlib\inftrees.c zlib\trees.c zlib\uncompr.c zlib\zutil.c
set  rc6=zopfli\blocksplitter.c zopfli\cache.c zopfli\deflate.c zopfli\gzip_container.c zopfli\hash.c zopfli\katajainen.c
set  rc7=zopfli\lz77.c zopfli\squeeze.c zopfli\tree.c zopfli\util.c zopfli\zlib_container.c zopfli\zopfli_lib.c
set  rcA=_asm\masmx86\inffas32.obj _asm\masmx86\match686.obj

set  def=-DZLIB_CONST -DASMV -DASMINF -DNDEBUG
set  inc=-Igalib -Izlib -Izopfli
set  lib=-L"i686-w64-mingw32\lib" -lws2_32 -lstdc++
set  lnk=-Wl,-flto,--no-insert-timestamp,--gc-sections,--disable-runtime-pseudo-reloc,--relax,--stats -s -static

set ops=-m32 -march=core2 -mtune=core2 -msse2 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fopenmp -ansi -flto -flto-partition=none -funroll-all-loops -floop-interchange -funsafe-loop-optimizations -funsafe-math-optimizations

"%exe%" %src% %rc1% %rc2% %rc3% %rc4% %rc5% %rc6% %rc7% %rcA% %def% %inc% %lib% %ops% %lnk% -o "%out%.exe"
```

У некоторых пользователей Windows, при запуске скомпилированного файла выдает ошибку:

```
Problem signature:
Problem event name: APPCRASH
Application name: pngwolfzopfli.exe
Application version: 0.0.0.0
Appendix time mark: 5f62525f
Module name with a mistake: pngwolfzopfli.exe
The version of the module with a mistake: 0.0.0.0
Module time mark with a mistake: 5f62525f
Exception code: c000001d
Shift of an exception: 000293be
Version of OS: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
Language code: 1049
Additional data 1: 0a9e
Additional data 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional data 3: 0a9e
Additional data 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Study the statement for confidentiality on the Internet:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?link...8&clcid=0x0419

If the statement for confidentiality on the Internet is inaccessible, examine its local option:
C:\Windows\system32\ru-RU\erofflps.txt
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему так происходит? Причем я заметил ошибка выдfется вне зависимости от версии Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

видите в выводе `Exception code` равный c000001d. Это значит "The system cannot write to the specified device." - то есть, программа пыталась куда то записать, но диска такого нет. В коде я явного указания имен файлов нет, но запись есть.

Мой вердикт - пользователи пытались указать в параметрах файл для записи, куда нельзя записать.

Comment: Интересно получается. Если компилировать данное приложение с теми параметрами которые указал автор, то такой ошибки нет.

Comment: тогда покажите  что именно поменяли в параметрах компиляции.

Comment: честно говоря, не я менял параметры компиляции. Вот оригинальный параметры https://github.com/jibsen/pngwolf-zopfli/blob/master/Makefile, а я использовал вот эти http://encode.ru/threads/1703-pngout-vs-pngwolf-zopfli?p=45426&viewfull=1#post45426, изменял параметры по этой причине http://encode.ru/threads/1703-pngout-vs-pngwolf-zopfli?p=44257&viewfull=1#post44257